# Configure APC for maximum hit rate

Tags: configuration, php5, alternative-php-cache

I'm currently running php5 with APC, the latter with default configuration. However after setting up munin to monitor APC, I'm surprised by the results:

- apc.shm_size: 30
- apc.gc_ttl: 3600
- apc.ttl: 0
- Used: 14MB
- Request rate: 100 requests/second
- Fragmentation: 0
- Hit ratio: 80% (dropping to 0 a few times per hour)

So the obvious question: how can I adapt the configuration to achieve a higher hitrate. I find it very strange that the available memory is not fully used which the hitratio is still below what I would expect.

Thank for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was caused by running PHP in CGI/FastCGI mode. PHP Processes spawned by this do not share the APC cache, and as such my monitoring results are completely incorrect.

To resolve this, I have configured my apache to start working with FPM/FastCGI for php using  mod_fastcgi. PHP's CPU usage has dropped impressively and caching is now done properly!